Segger Embedded Studio Linking .elf Build Error
I am trying to build an example project in Segger Embedded Studio 5.62. The project was building fine and working as intended. After I closed out of the project and opened it again without making any changes to the code, my build is failing every time. I am using macOS ARM. The transcript output gives me little to no information on whats causing the error. The last lines just read the following 1> Generating linker script ‘nRF52833DK-QANI-FreeRTOS.ld’
1> Linking nRF52833DK-QANI-FreeRTOS.elf
1> Post-Building ‘nRF52833DK-QANI-FreeRTOS’
Build failed
Any one know what could be going on? I appreciate any help and anyone's time in advance!

Did you try Build -> Clean and then rebuild?

I'd expect Segger Embedded Studio to provide options to see the full command line and output of the linker call, or at least some log file with this information. Did you try to look for that? When you found it, please [edit] your question and add it.
